# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state' when checking if something exists in the DB

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to Flask/SQLA and I'm creating a small learning application where users can view US national parks (using the National Park Service API). I would like to allow logged in users to save parks to their favorites list to view later.

The parks table starts empty since we're just getting the info from the API. If a user adds a park to their favorites, we're checking to see if that particular park is in the DB or not. If not, we add it. There is only two columns: an autoincrementing ID, and a park code. The API I'm using assigns a four letter code to each park. For example Yosemite National Park is "yose".

When I try to add a park as my favorite, I get `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'`. This is the route that handles adding a park to favorites:

```
@app.route("/<username>/add-favorite/<park_code>", methods=['POST'])
def add_favorites(username, park_code):
"""Add park to favorites"""

if "username" not in session or username != session['username']:
    flash("You must be logged in to access this page")
    return redirect("/login")

user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
favorited_park = Park.query.filter_by(park_code=park_code) is not None 

# if park already in the DB 
if favorited_park:
    **user.parks.append(favorited_park)**
    db.session.commit() 
    flash("Existing park has been added to favorites")
    return redirect("/<username>/favorite-parks")

# if the park is not already in the DB 
else:
    park = Park(park_code=park_code)
    **user.parks.append(favorited_park)**
    db.session.commit() 
    flash("Favorite park has been added") 
    return redirect("/<username>/favorite-parks")
```

The line above that is raising the error is `​user.parks.append(favorited_park)`.

And this is **models.py**

```
class User(db.Model):
"""User"""

__tablename__ = "users" 

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
password = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

parks = db.relationship("Park", secondary="users_parks", backref="user")


class Park(db.Model):
"""Park"""

__tablename__ = "parks"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
park_code = db.Column(db.String(4), unique=True, nullable=False)

users = db.relationship("User", secondary="users_parks", backref="favorite_parks")  



class UserPark(db.Model):
"""Mapping of a user to a park"""

__tablename__ = "users_parks" 

user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True)
park_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("parks.id"), primary_key=True) 


def connect_db(app):
"""Connect to database."""

db.app = app
db.init_app(app)
```

I'd appreciate any pointers to overcome this error.

Comment: Replace `is not None` with `.first()`. In the else-branch you want to `user.parks.append(park)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
favorited_park = Park.query.filter_by(park_code=park_code) is not None
```

I'll demonstrate the statement in two parts, first:

```py
Park.query.filter_by(park_code=park_code)
```

This returns an instance of `<class 'flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery'>`. That is, a query that is yet to be executed. To actually execute a query, you need to call an execution method (see [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#returning-lists-and-scalars)), or iterate over the query instance.

The key point I'm making is that in the context of that statement, the result of this part is never `None`, and always a query instance.

Then consider that in the context of the second part of that statement (and a bit of pseudo code):

```py
favorited_park = <class 'flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery'> is not None
```

Some thing that is never `None` tested against whether it is not `None` will always return `True`.

This is the same as:

```py
1 is not None  # True
"a string" is not None  # True
object() is not None  # True
```

So, that line is essentially this:

```py
favorited_park = True
```

Continuing on, this line:

```py
if favorited_park:
```

Evaluates truthy, as `favorited_park` is `True`, so execution enters that guarded block of code. Then this line:

```py
user.parks.append(favorited_park)
```

Is where the error is thrown as sqlalchemy won't allow you to append a boolean value to an instrumented collection.

To correct the error, you need to call one of those execution methods on the query to either return an instance of `Park` or `None`. One option might be [`Query.one_or_none()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one_or_none), which from the docs:

> Returns None if the query selects no rows. Raises
> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.MultipleResultsFound if multiple object identities
> are returned, or if multiple rows are returned for a query that
> returns only scalar values as opposed to full identity-mapped
> entities.

So that line might become:

```py
favorited_park = Park.query.filter_by(park_code=park_code).one_or_none()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer.